# Creating folders using GCP PHP Client Libraries

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform

I started learning Google Cloud Storage PHP Client Library through documentation given by Google. But following questions are uncleared.

1. How to create a folder in a bucket?
2. How to create a folder in a folder?
3. How to list all the files in a folder?

I have learnt that folders are nothing but objects with "/" at the end of their name. Also we can upload an object using `$bucket->upload()` method to upload an object. This method needs a path of file so it is creating a trouble to create a folder

Comment: Folders do not actually exist in Cloud Storage Buckets. The namespace is flat. The impression of folders is emulated by the Google Cloud Console and other tools. The files `/MyFolder/test.txt` and `/YourFolder/test.txt` are at the same level (same directory) in the bucket (at the root level) - I am ignoring object name hashing. Tools use the `/` character as a separator to emulate folders. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork

Comment: @JohnHanley please move your comment to an answer :D

Comment: @J.A.Hernández - Thank you, completed.

Comment: Your question is still open. Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @JohnHanley yes, I sorted it out.

Comment: What was the solution? Do not leave questions open. Select an answer, post your own answer or delete the question.

Comment: @John Oh sorry. I am quite new to this platform. i will post answer separately now

Comment: @JohnHanley I have posted my answer. Is there anything else I have to do now?

Comment: Answering your own question is great. This benefits the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to question1**: Creating empty folders is possible only via cloud console. You cannot create empty folder in a GCP bucket via SDK functions. Suppose if you wanted to create, `/test` folder in a bucket, upload a file named `/test/file.txt`. Make sure that the files you upload later in that `/test` folder to be other than `file.txt`

**Answer to question2**: Almost identical to first question except paths

**Answer to question3**: Listing items in a particular directory can be done using extra parameters like delimiters, prefixes provided by GCP SDK.

Comment: Technically this is OK to do. However, some backup programs will break as they do not expect an object with the same name as a prefix. There are commercial software packages that use this technique to emulate folders. The difference is that they also include metadata indicating that the object is a pseudo-folder with additional information regarding file, group, other, permissions, etc. This technique is vendor unique.

Answer (score 2):

Folders do not actually exist in Cloud Storage Buckets. The namespace is flat. The impression of folders is emulated by the Google Cloud Console and other tools. The files `/MyFolder/test.txt` and `/YourFolder/test.txt` are at the same level (same directory) in the bucket (at the root level) - I am ignoring object name hashing. Tools use the `/` character as a separator (delimitor) to emulate folders.

[How Subdirectories Work](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork)

When working with the Google Cloud Storage REST API, directories are listed by using a `delimeter=/` and specifying a prefix for the directory name, example:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/MYBUCKETNAME/o?prefix=MyDirectory/?delimiter=/
```

This URL informs the REST API that you want to list the object names that start with `MyDirectory/` breaking on object names that continue after the next delimiter, example:

```
MyDirectory/file1.txt
MyDirectory/file2.txt
MyDirectory/something/file3.txt
```

Note that nowhere in the namespace is the object name (directory) `MyDirectory` or `MyDirectory/something` stored. That is just derived from the object names using prefixes and delimiters.

The above URL will list the first two objects. The third will be skipped.

The API returns JSON data, and there are two types of data returned:

1. `items`, which return the object names that start with `prefix` and do not contain a  `delimiter` after the prefix.
2. `prefixes`, which returns the object names truncated by the delimiter - which provides the equivalent of directory names.

In other words, the illusion of directories and their contents is just a fancy parsing trick performed by the Google Cloud Storage API.